# CSS Styles not giving the expected result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the same CSS styles for two different elements of different panels, but one shows the text I would like, while the other doesn't. The relevant css file is named grid.css.

I am linking to the currently hosted version of my website, which has the relevant issue: https://nanomotions.org/

I'm not sure if it has to do with the javascript linked to the element or if video files inherently move over text, so I've decided to link the full website for easier debugging of the cause. Here is the relevant github: https://github.com/kaweepatinn1/kaweepatinn1.github.io

I've tried messing around with the css settings, looking around for the element in inspect element, ect, but I can't seem to see the problem when one element works perfectly with supposedly the same CSS code.

Here is the area of HTML in question:

```
      <a href="TO SET">
<div class="applead grid-item" onmouseover="regifApple()" onmouseleave="revertApple()">
<img class="img" id="appleimage" width="100%" height="auto" src="./static/assets/applead.webp" alt="Applead Image">
  <div class="img-caption">
    <div class="vid-title">
      Mock Apple Ad
    </div>
    <div class="vid-director">
      Animation and Motion Graphics
    </div>
  </div>
</img>
</div>
</a>
<a href="TO SET">
  <div class="OYYGC grid-item" onmouseover="regifOYYGC()">
  <video class="img" id="OYYGCimage" width="100%" height="auto" src="./static/assets/OYYGC.mp4" loop muted="muted" alt="OYYGC">
    <div class="img-caption">
      <div class="vid-title">
        Oh Yeah You Gonna Cry?
      </div>
      <div class="vid-director">
        Animated x Live Music Video
      </div>
    </div>
  </video>
  </div>
  </a>
```

The CSS for these classes:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }

.grid-item{
    height: 17w;
    margin: 1vw;
}

.vid-title{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:1vw;
    letter-spacing:0.2vw;
    color:white;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
    transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
    padding:0px 15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.vid-director{
    color:white;
    opacity:0.5;
    font-size:0.5vw;
    letter-spacing:0.1vw;
    font-weight:100;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:5px;
}

.img {
    transition: filter 0.3s ease;
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }

.applead {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
  
.applead img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.applead .img-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  }

.applead:hover .img-caption {
    opacity: 1;
  }

.applead:hover .img {
    filter: brightness(50%);
  }

.OYYGC {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
  
.OYYGC img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.OYYGC .img-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  }

.OYYGC:hover .img-caption {
    opacity: 1;
  }

.OYYGC:hover .img {
    filter: brightness(50%);
  }
```

javascript, if relevant:

```
var mouseOverApple = false;
var mouseWasGoneApple = true;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
         if($("#appleimage:hover").length != 0){
            mouseOverApple = true;
        } else{
            mouseOverApple = false;
        }
        if($("#OYYGCimage:hover").length != 0){
            mouseOverOYYGC = true;
        } else{
            mouseOverOYYGC = false;
            revertOYYGC();
        }
    });
});

function regifApple(){
    if (mouseWasGoneApple == true){
    let content = document.getElementById("appleimage");
    content.src = "./static/assets/applead.gif";
    mouseWasGoneApple = false;
    }
}

function revertApple(){
    if (mouseOverApple == false){
        let content = document.getElementById("appleimage");
        content.src = "./static/assets/applead.webp";
        mouseWasGoneApple = true;
    }
}

var mouseOverOYYGC = false;
var mouseWasGoneOYYGC = true;
var toActivateOYYGC = false;

function regifOYYGC(){
    if (mouseWasGoneOYYGC == true){
    let content = document.getElementById("OYYGCimage");
    content.play();
    mouseWasGoneOYYGC = false;
    }
}

function revertOYYGC(){
    let content = document.getElementById("OYYGCimage");
    content.pause();
    content.currentTime = 0;
    mouseWasGoneOYYGC = true;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid - there is no `</img>` tag - images are self-closing or empty elements. Having nested HTML content within an image is just nonsense

Comment: You're also using HTML `width` and `height` attributes and shouldn't be. Set ALL styles with CSS, not with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, you cannot directly place a `<div>` element inside a `<video>` tag. The `<video>` element is designed to display video content, and it cannot contain block-level elements like `<div>`.

Instead, you should structure your HTML differently if you want to overlay content on top of a video or position content around a video element.

The simple way to fix your problem is to take out the `div` tag with `class="img-caption"` outside of the `<video>` tag as shown below:

```
<a href="TO SET">
    <div class="OYYGC grid-item" onmouseover="regifOYYGC()" bis_skin_checked="1">
        <video class="img" id="OYYGCimage" width="100%" height="auto" src="./static/assets/OYYGC.mp4" loop="" muted="muted" alt="OYYGC"></video>
        <div class="img-caption" bis_skin_checked="1" style="pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="vid-title" bis_skin_checked="1">Oh Yeah You Gonna Cry?</div>
            <div class="vid-director" bis_skin_checked="1">Animated x Live Music Video</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Add the `pointer-events:none` in CSS here.

```
.OYYGC .img-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.OYYGC .img-caption .vid-director {
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow explain what the OPs problem was and how their code fixes it. Code dump answers, like this (even if they are correct) are not good answers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your suggestion. I will edit my answer with an explanation.

Comment: That's true, all I know is that it's something to do with pointer events.

Comment: Do you also know how I would align the text to the video, without the padding? It's currently being aligned to the full grid and hence the text is outside of the video at the bottom.

Comment: You have given bottom: 5px for .vid-director class, you can increase few pixels for video tag. Like this:  .OYYGC .img-caption .vid-director {bottom: 15px;}

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you've placed the `img-caption` as a child of the video element, so it would only ever be shown if a users [browser doesn't support the video tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).

Based on the source code in your repo, this is what you should be using:

```
<div class="OYYGC grid-item" onmouseover="regifOYYGC()">
  <video class="img" id="OYYGCimage" width="100%" height="auto" src="./static/assets/OYYGC.mp4" loop muted="muted" alt="OYYGC"></video>
  <div class="img-caption">
    <div class="vid-title">
      Oh Yeah You Gonna Cry?
    </div>
    <div class="vid-director">
      Animated x Live Music Video
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, video will not play in case of hover.

Comment: The pointer-events property would likely be your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: So using this code, the text seems to be using the full grid, including the padding to align itself, displaying outside of the video. This is fine, i can probably fix it using some realignment. 

However, I'm not sure how to use pointer events to play the video again; I've tried putting the pointer-events: auto; css tag onto the image class, but I dont think it does anything.